# Where is groovy.json.JsonSlurper in groovy 1.7.8

Tags: json, grails, httpbuilder

I am running Grails 1.3.7; I have server A that needs to make a POST request on server B. I am using the [http-builder](http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/doc/rest.html) library to make these requests. The request seems to be composed correctly

```
RESTClient http = new RESTClient( searchServerUrl );

Map body = ...;     
logger.trace("request: ${request}, body: ${body}")
def response = http.post( path: request, body: body, requestContentType: URLENC)
logger.trace("response: ${response}");
return response;
```

Server B performs the computation correctly, and returns a JSON structure to server A. When Server A tries to parse it, I see a long stack of exceptions rooted here:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: groovy/json/JsonSlurper
at groovyx.net.http.ParserRegistry.parseJSON(ParserRegistry.java:280)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
... 145 more
```

**EDITED**
The `http-builder` library comes with `groovy-1.8.8.jar` in its `dependencies` folder, but I would rather use the standard Groovy library  (v. 1.7.8) that comes with my Grails runtime. Unfortunately, the `groovy.json` namespace doesn't seem to be there. What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because [http-builder-0.6](http://repository.codehaus.org/org/codehaus/groovy/modules/http-builder/http-builder/0.6/) is based on Groovy 1.8.8, it assumes that the JSONSlurper class is available with the Groovy libraries. Since I was using a version of Grails that comes with Groovy 1.7.8, I did not have that library. At this stage there were two choices: upgrade the app to a more recent grails version, or downgrade the http-builder library to one that includes the JSON classes explicitly. I opted for the second solution (upgrading from Grails 1.3.7 to 2.2 is not trivial), and was able to get my code to work with [http-builder-0.5.2](http://repository.codehaus.org/org/codehaus/groovy/modules/http-builder/http-builder/0.5.2/).

Comment: Can you provide the solution for 2nd option. As i am not able to identify that how can we add JsonSlurper explicitly in http-builder. You help much appreciated. Thanks!